# ¿Cómo podría hacer mediante javascript que solamente se actualice la página una vez?

Tags: javascript, php, html

tengo el siguiente código de php combinado con javascript:

```
$updater = '<script>function actualizar(){location.reload(true);}
//Función para actualizar cada 5 segundos(5000 milisegundos)
setInterval("actualizar()",2000); </script>';

$user_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']; 
// Condiciones cookianas jeje
if ($user_agent === "facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)") {
    
    setcookie('Facebook', time()+31536000,'/');
    echo $updater;
    echo <<<EOT
    <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body  onload="timer = setTimeout('actualizar()',2000);">
    </body>
    </html>
    
    
    EOT;
    
}
```

¿Cómo podría modificarlo de tal manera que se actualizase solamente una vez?, no que fuese constante como lo es por el momento.
Quiero hacer esto debido a que al entrar el crawler de facebook se le asigna la cookie pero sin embargo al no haber un refresh no se le aplica hasta la siguiente entrada a la web.

Comment: basicamente haz la peticion al servidor con javascript y no con php, puedes usar fetch

Comment: No entiendo mucho, pero si usas php la opción sencilla es que uses SESSION y valides, ejemplo $_SESSON["Contador"]=0; y cuando cargue, lo cambias a "1" y colocas una condición que si no es 1 recargue y si es 0 no haga nada y listo

Answer (score 0):

Usa JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if(localStorage.getItem('refresh') == null){
        localStorage.setItem('refresh', '1')
        window.location = "";
    }
});
```

Si no existe el LS, refrescas y asignas un valor cualquira.